# How can I add jars from more than one unmanaged directory in an SBT .scala project configuration

Tags: scala, dependencies, project, sbt, unmanagedresources

I'm trying to get SBT to build a project that could have more than one unmanaged directory. If I had a single directory, I could  easily do it like this:

```
unmanagedBase := file( "custom-libs" ).getAbsoluteFile
```

But since I have two directories with unmanaged jars, I need to be able to add them all. I have found some information [in here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management), but still doesn't seem useful for my full **.scala** file build.

I have created a simple project that shows the issue [in here](https://github.com/mauricio/sbt-with-many-unmanaged-repos). And below is my **Build.scala** file.

**UPDATE**

I've got some help form the [sbt-users list](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/3b9aefc980fe73af#) and have been able to define the **unmanaged-jars** correctly, but the code still doesn't compile (but **sbt show unmanaged-jars** shows the files correctly).

```
import sbt._
import com.github.siasia._
import PluginKeys._
import Keys._

object Build extends sbt.Build {

  import Dependencies._

  val unmanagedListing = unmanagedJars :=  {
    Dependencies.listUnmanaged( file(".").getAbsoluteFile )
  }

  lazy val myProject = Project("spray-template", file("."))
    .settings(WebPlugin.webSettings: _*)
    .settings(port in config("container")  := 8080)
    .settings(
      organization  := "com.example",
      version       := "0.9.0-RC1",
      scalaVersion  := "2.9.1",
      scalacOptions := Seq("-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8"),
      resolvers     ++= Dependencies.resolutionRepos,
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        Compile.akkaActor,
        Compile.sprayServer,
        Test.specs2,
        Container.jettyWebApp,
        Container.akkaSlf4j,
        Container.slf4j,
        Container.logback
      ),
      unmanagedListing
    )

}

object Dependencies {
  val resolutionRepos = Seq(
    ScalaToolsSnapshots,
    "Typesafe repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
    "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.cc/"
  )

  def listUnmanaged( base : RichFile ) : Keys.Classpath = {
    val baseDirectories = (base / "custom-libs") +++ ( base / "custom-libs2" )
    (baseDirectories ** "*.jar").classpath
  }

  object V {
    val akka    = "1.3"
    val spray   = "0.9.0-RC1"
    val specs2  = "1.7.1"
    val jetty   = "8.1.0.v20120127"
    val slf4j   = "1.6.4"
    val logback = "1.0.0"
  }

  object Compile {
    val akkaActor   = "se.scalablesolutions.akka" %  "akka-actor"      % V.akka    % "compile"
    val sprayServer = "cc.spray"                  %  "spray-server"    % V.spray   % "compile"
  }

  object Test {
    val specs2      = "org.specs2"                %% "specs2"          % V.specs2  % "test"
  }

  object Container {
    val jettyWebApp = "org.eclipse.jetty"         %  "jetty-webapp"    % V.jetty   % "container"
    val akkaSlf4j   = "se.scalablesolutions.akka" %  "akka-slf4j"      % V.akka
    val slf4j       = "org.slf4j"                 %  "slf4j-api"       % V.slf4j
    val logback     = "ch.qos.logback"            %  "logback-classic" % V.logback
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by [Eugene Vigdorchik](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/msg/dd19f63d93b097b8), what made it work as the following code:

```
import sbt._
import com.github.siasia._
import PluginKeys._
import Keys._

object Build extends sbt.Build {

  import Dependencies._

  var unmanagedListing = unmanagedJars in Compile :=  {
    Dependencies.listUnmanaged( file(".").getAbsoluteFile )
  }

  lazy val myProject = Project("spray-template", file("."))
    .settings(WebPlugin.webSettings: _*)
    .settings(port in config("container")  := 8080)
    .settings(
      organization  := "com.example",
      version       := "0.9.0-RC1",
      scalaVersion  := "2.9.1",
      scalacOptions := Seq("-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8"),
      resolvers     ++= Dependencies.resolutionRepos,
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        C.akkaActor,
        C.sprayServer,
        Test.specs2,
        Container.jettyWebApp,
        Container.akkaSlf4j,
        Container.slf4j,
        Container.logback
      ),
      unmanagedListing
    )

}

object Dependencies {
  val resolutionRepos = Seq(
    ScalaToolsSnapshots,
    "Typesafe repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
    "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.cc/"
  )

  def listUnmanaged( base : RichFile ) : Keys.Classpath = {
    val baseDirectories = (base / "custom-libs") +++ ( base / "custom-libs2" )
    (baseDirectories ** "*.jar").classpath
  }

  object V {
    val akka    = "1.3"
    val spray   = "0.9.0-RC1"
    val specs2  = "1.7.1"
    val jetty   = "8.1.0.v20120127"
    val slf4j   = "1.6.4"
    val logback = "1.0.0"
  }

  object C {
    val akkaActor   = "se.scalablesolutions.akka" %  "akka-actor"      % V.akka    % "compile"
    val sprayServer = "cc.spray"                  %  "spray-server"    % V.spray   % "compile"
  }

  object Test {
    val specs2      = "org.specs2"                %% "specs2"          % V.specs2  % "test"
  }

  object Container {
    val jettyWebApp = "org.eclipse.jetty"         %  "jetty-webapp"    % V.jetty   % "container"
    val akkaSlf4j   = "se.scalablesolutions.akka" %  "akka-slf4j"      % V.akka
    val slf4j       = "org.slf4j"                 %  "slf4j-api"       % V.slf4j
    val logback     = "ch.qos.logback"            %  "logback-classic" % V.logback
  }
}
```

Source repo with the full example [available on Github](https://github.com/mauricio/sbt-with-many-unmanaged-repos).

Answer (score 8):

I just post the fragment from my `build.sbt` file, using sbt **0.11.x**. It could probably be refactored a bit.

```
unmanagedJars in Compile <++= baseDirectory map { base =>
    val libs = base / "lib"
    val dirs = (libs / "batik") +++ (libs / "libtw") +++ (libs / "kiama")
    (dirs ** "*.jar").classpath
}
```

Comment: I dont have a build.sbt file, were do i place this on my Build.scala file?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Have you tried simply adding those lines to your `Build.scala` file?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Have you adapted my code? It is for directories `lib/batik`, `lib/libtw` and `lib/kiama`.

Comment: Of course I have. Adding prints on it shows it is never called, just as my own code above, so it did not overrite the unmanagedJars task.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are actually overriding `unmanagedJars` with the very first line in your `Build`. Have you tried just using my code and not fiddling with `unmanagedJars` otherwise?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Are you sure you wrote `unmanagedJars in Compile`, exactly like that, including upper and lower cases?

Comment: Here is a project https://github.com/mauricio/sbt-with-many-unmanaged-repos that represents the issue, this is exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can add additional paths to the list of folders to scan for unmanaged dependencies.  For example, to look in a folder called "config" in addition to "lib" for the `run` task, you can add the following.  For the `compile` task change `Runtime` to `Compile`.

```
unmanagedClasspath in Runtime <+= (baseDirectory) map {
  bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "config")
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. A sample project showing the issue is here -> https://github.com/mauricio/sbt-with-many-unmanaged-repos - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a general solution to recursive loading of unmanaged JARs (for sbt 0.13.x): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357699/1348306