# SBT accessing sub directories

Tags: scala, build-automation, sbt

My project file structure looks like this:

- build.sbt
- lib
- project
- src
- target
- test

Inside `lib` folder I have sub folders that contain additional jar files. How can I get SBT to recognize sub-folders or to treat jar files recursively?

EDIT:
thanks to @Jhonny Everson I am able to get this working. Here is how:
added the following line in my build.sbt

```
unmanagedJars in Compile <++= baseDirectory map { base =>
        val baseDirectories = (base / "lib" / "mycustomlib" )
        val customJars = (baseDirectories ** "*.jar")
        customJars.classpath
}
```

Note that the base directory is where build.sbt is located.

Comment: +1 because you added the solution that worked for you as an edit. That is really helpful when searching for answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put jars on lib folder, Sbt will use them automatically. You can use `unmanagedJars` directive to specify multiple directories in which jar files can be found. See https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management#manual-dependency-management

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to implement something like vim's pathogen and here's what I came up with:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile ++= {
  val libs = baseDirectory.value / "lib"
  val subs = (libs ** "*") filter { _.isDirectory }
  val targets = ( (subs / "target") ** "*" ) filter {f => f.name.startsWith("scala-") && f.isDirectory}
  ((libs +++ subs +++ targets) ** "*.jar").classpath
}
```

Using **sbt 0.13.x** or any typesafe-activator relying on it, this will check `/lib`, `/lib/*` and `/lib/*/target/scala-*` for JARs and load them into the classpath. If the example isn't clear enough to understand what's going on, it might help to know that `baseDirectory.value`, `libs`, `subs` and `targets` are [sbt.Pathfinder](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.PathFinder) instances.